# Difficulty in understanding amplitude probability calculation

Tags: quantum-mechanics

I am trying to understand methodology of amplitude probability. I know, that when I have amplitude $
langle x \vert y \rangle$ the amplitude is:
\begin{equation}
\lvert \langle x \vert y \rangle \rvert^{2}=\langle x \vert y \rangle\langle y \vert x \rangle
\end{equation}
But let's say we have state $|w>$ which can be decomposed on two states:

- $\lvert v \rangle$ along the polarization axis
- $\lvert h \rangle$ perpendicular to polarization axis
  So we have:
  \begin{equation}
  \lvert w \rangle = \lvert v \rangle\langle v\vert w\rangle + \lvert h\rangle \langle w \rvert
  \end{equation}
  and the probability here (from what I've learned so far) is equal to
  \begin{equation}
  \lvert \langle v \vert w \rangle \rvert^{2}
  \end{equation}
  My question is - what has happened with $\lvert v \rangle$. The most reasonable solution I could come up with is the fact that because $\lvert \lvert v \rangle \rvert^{2}$ is equal to $1$ we omit it. Because as I understand we should in fact have here:
  \begin{equation}
  \lvert \lvert v \rangle \rvert^{2} * \lvert \langle v \vert w \rangle \rvert^{2}
  \end{equation}
  this way $\lvert \lvert v \rangle \rvert^{2}$ cannot be $0$.
  But is this all correct? How does it actually work?

Comment: You want `\langle`,  `\lvert`, `\vert`, `\rvert`, and `\rangle` for writing bra-ket notation: $\lvert w \rangle = \lvert v \rangle\langle v\vert w\rangle + \lvert h\rangle \langle w \rvert$. They will also scale in size when needed (as when indicating the absolute values) or which you would also use `\lvert` and `\rvert`. I did this one for you, but you should check my work: make sure I didn't mess up your math.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need your kets to be orthogonal and normalised, so if you have some state that is made up out of some eigenkets:
$$ | \psi \rangle = \sum_i a_{i}|i\rangle$$, where $|i\rangle$ are eigenkets of some operator corresponding to a physical observable, then probability to measure the eigenvalue of $|i\rangle$ when taking a measurement of corresponding observable is given by $$ P_i = |a_i|^2$$ if $$\langle j|i\rangle = \delta_{ij}$$ and $$ | | \psi \rangle|^2=1 , \ i.e. \sum_i a_i^2 = 1 $$ where $\delta$ is Kronecker delta. In simple words, that means that your states have to be properly normalised and orthogonal. Second part should be fairly intuitive if you think about it: if your states are not orthogonal, that means some of them can be expanded in terms of the rest, that means some of them are a mix of states, so measuring that kind of a state just physically doesn't make much sense (I am mixing linear independence and orthogonality here, but I think in case of those kinds of vector spaces they are equivalent). In your case, need $ \langle v |v \rangle =1 $, i.e. $|v \rangle $ is normalised (just imagine it in the same sense as you imagine usual Cartesian vectors to be normalised), and $| v \rangle$ and $| w \rangle$ are orthogonal, AND $| \langle v | v \rangle |^2 + | \langle w | w \rangle |^2  = 1$. Then you are fine to extract the probabilities.